# What's the word for a conjugation dictionary?

Tags: demande-de-mot

What's the word for a conjugation dictionary? I saw it few months ago on the internet completely by accident but I can't find it again now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a proper word, but most people will talk about a Bescherelle (http://bescherelle.com/) from the brand name of the most used (if not only one) book of this type in French.

In case of a better answer, I'll delete this one.

Comment: There's also the Robert & Nathan: https://www.amazon.fr/Robert-Nathan-conjugaison-Collectif/dp/2091803308

Answer (score 4):

As per @MakorDal 's answer, it is very common to refer to such books as

> un bescherelle

However, I believe the technical term for them is simply:

> un dictionnaire de conjugaison

Comment: On utilise beaucoup dans le langage courant "un bescherelle", mais l'ennui c'est que c'est une marque. Pour un "dictionnarie de conjugaison" je vote.

Answer (score 0):

On utilise aussi "un conjugueur", c'est un néologisme, mais il de plus en plus employé sur internet, chaque site qui donne des conseils ou des leçons en français a maintenant son "conjugueur".
Il a l'avantage de ne pas citer de marque, comme "Bescherelle".
Sinon oui, le terme traditionnel était "dictionnaire de conjugaison".